# Split a jsp method in multiple scriplets to include html code in between

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am writing a method in JSP which dump rows of a table:

```
<%!  
    void dumpRows(List<MyClass> obList){  
        int a = 10;  
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){  
%>  
   //lots of HTML code which uses the variables from the dumpRows method  
   <td> <%=a*i%> </td>  
<%  
        }//for loop ends  
    }//method ends  
%>
```

but it is erroring out. There's something wrong with the JSP grammar. Please help me on how can I achieve that

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: it doesn't compile. it expects a '}' in the first part of the scriplet to close the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are mixing `<%!`, `<%` and `<%=`.
If you separate business logic and view it will be much easier and clear.
You can use JSTL tag `<c:forEach>` to output your html table.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%!  
    void dumpRows(List<MyClass> obList){  
        int a = 10;  
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){  
%>  
   //lots of HTML code which uses the variables from the dumpRows method  
   <td> <%=a*i%> </td>                 //here problem
<%  
        }//for loop ends  
    }//method ends  
%>
```

write this way to print <%=a*i%>

Comment: Sorry but the answer is pretty unreadable. Also, please mention the solution as well instead of just pointing out the problem

Comment: as far as i understand you just wanted to print the value of a*i so to print on a jsp page you should write this way<%=%> but in your code you are writing <%>

Comment: Thanx but that was a typing mistake only here. I have edited the question now.